# Connecting to Redis on VM from my localhost PHP application

Tags: php, redis, predis

I have an Ubuntu VM with Redis installed, running on my Windows PC. I have a PHP application that uses Predis to interface with Redis:

```
Predis\Autoloader::register();

try {
  $redis = new Predis\Client(array(
      "scheme" => "tcp",
      "host" => "192.168.1.66",
      "port" => 6379
  ));
$redis->set('foo', 'bar');

}
catch (Exception $e) {
  die($e->getMessage());
}
```

My Redis.conf has #bind 127.0.0.1 commented out, protected-mode no, and port 6379 (I restarted Redis after the change). I can access Redis inside the VM through the redis-cli with no issues, but when trying to access it via my localhost PHP application I continually get:

No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. [tcp://192.168.1.66:6379]

Are there any other configuration options needed for my localhost app to reach the VM Redis instance?

*updated with the correct ip address. Issue persists. Also to note my VM network adapter is set to bridge and I can ping the VM from my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Is the VM's IP `localhost(127.0.0.1)`?
Check VM's IP.

Comment: Updated with the correct IP. Still having the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Get the IP of your VM(should be something like 192.168.*.*) and bind your redis server to that IP. Then try accessing the redis server with that ip and port(6379).

Answer (score 0):

You can ping the VM but can you access its port 6379?

Try a tool like telnet or netcat.

Comment: telnet 192.168.1.66 6379 results in: Connecting To 192.168.1.66...Could not open connection to the host, on port 6379
: Connect failed

Comment: Based on the IP format, I assume this is controlled by a router of yours. Is that right? If so, you may need to explicitly open the port 6379

Comment: Yes DHCP. I tried explicitly opening the port on the router. Still the same issue. Not really sure what else to look for at this point.